# TwitterAPI for Python: using result from request in a new request

Tags: python, twitter

I want to collect all user data from the followers from a specific twitter user. First, I collect the user_id's of the followers from the user using followers/id. Thereafter I want to use users/lookup in order to collect the user data from the collected user_id's all at once (with a maximum of 100). This is where I get stuck, I don't seem to get any results. I think it has something to do with the input user_ids since inputting them manually gives me the results I expect.

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
import JSON

consumer_key = "..."
consumer_secret = "..."
access_token = "..."
access_token_secret = "..."

api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

r = api.request('followers/ids', {'screen_name':'elonmusk'})
r = json.loads(r.text)
r = list(r['ids'])
f = api.request('users/lookup', {'user_id': r })
print(f.text)
```

I've tried several devious ways to solve it, but the above mentioned is for as far as my beginner python knowledge ranges the most reliable. Although it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it myself. The first request yielded too many results, which the second request couldn't process. I changed the first request to this:

```
r = api.request('followers/ids', {'screen_name':'elonmusk', 'count':'100'})
```